# How does multiplying damage work in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am having trouble calculating how much damage my character can do in one attack.
I get multipliers from various sources:

- 100 one-handed skill(because 100 skill lvl = 1.4x to the base damage. See the formula for some information)
- 5 perks for Armsman(double damage).
- no weapon bonus damage enchantment items.
- sneak attack (x15 with daggers).
- shrouded gloves from dark brotherhood (makes the sneak attack 30x.)
- dualwielding legendary daedric daggers(thats base damage of about 21 each).
- power attacking(double damage with 50% bonus from dual wielding perk (also does standing power attack get thrown in while sneaking?).
- getting a critical hit(double damage if I'm not mistaken).
- and if I'm not forgetting anything using the Berzerker orc power(doubles damage).

My question is, what kind of damage multiplier am I looking at here?

According to [the UESP page on weapons in Skyrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Weapons), the damage formula is:

```
displayed damage = (base damage + smithing upgrade)
                 * (1 + 0.4 * skill/100)
                 * (1 + perk % damage boosts)
                 * (1 + % damage from items)
```

Comment: Sneak attack w/ dagger + the backstab bonus *will* make for a 30x damage.

Comment: i thought the 15x damage was /w the backstab bonus? anyway when damage gets doubled a la power attack or dual wielding power attack, how does that add up? i did some calculations and got a 720x multiplier, which can't be right because with some serious cheese you can get into 10's of thousands of damage in one hit

Comment: The stealth perk brings daggers up to 15x. The Shrouded Gloves double that, to 30x. This multiplier is shown on-screen when you sneak attack with a dagger - the other multipliers aren't displayed, but they should stack, and **yes** it quickly reaches ridiculous amounts of damage.

Comment: thanks raven, im going to test this out tonight and give an answer based on my findings.

Comment: Daggers are a poor choice to test this with. There's currently a bug that prevents them from fully benefitting from Fortify 1H enchants and effects.

Comment: do you mean to say it doesnt factor in one handed skill and perk multipliers? because im testing this without any enchantments.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to crit with daggers.

Comment: @Andrew actually it should be, there's even a dagger in the game that improves critical chance by 25%, would be weird if they put that on the dagger yet not allow critical hits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While wielding  a daedric dagger, having 100 one handed(all perks) and 100 sneak(all perks), the daedric dagger's base damage showed as 33. From the dagger's sneak attack(only 15x damage) it caused around 500 damage. Then I applied a power attack and it caused 1,000 damage. Then my orc used berzerk and a single strike caused 2,000 damage.

I could do some more testing (like getting shroud gloves, dual wielding with a power attack doesnt do a single hit unfortunately), and having bonus one handed damage enchants(it modifies the displayed base damage btw), but I think this is enough to show that multipliers stack (15x + 2x = 30x + 2x = 60x) instead of combine(15x + 2x = 16x + 2x = 17x).

Comment: still not sure about power attacks and perks while sneaking. i used the console and setav health 10000 to someone and gauged the damage by how much the bar decreased. the damage is an estimate at most but still a large amount.

Comment: you can measure actual damage by getav health, but its definitely multiplicative, at least for the backstab gloves.

Comment: One handed enchants do not affect a daggers damage, neither do one handed skill perks.

Comment: 1H skill perks do modify dagger damage, but 1H enchants do not(a bug). A more helpful bug is that Fortify Marksman potions buff damage to all weapons.

Answer (score -1):

I know the sneak ones stack for sure.

You can see this easy by getting the Dark Brotherhood gloves. It'll tell you that you did 30x damage.

Comment: thats obvious, because the gloves say it doubles the sneak attack bonus