# Do power attack perks in Skyrim apply to sneak power attacks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was wondering about this from [How does multiplying damage work in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38485/how-does-multiplying-damage-work-in-skyrim) I'm not sure if the perk Savage Strike applies to the damage while standing still and sneaking. By the perk description, it increases all "standing" power attacks by 25%. However, while sneak attacking and standing still you aren't "standing" more than you are crouching.

tldr; Does Savage Strike work on "crouching" sneak power attacks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Sneak Attack is not the same thing as a Power Attack. However, you can perform a power attack while sneaking. These power attacks are affected by all of the normal modifiers.

Comment: Does "normal modifers" include the sneak attack modifier?

Comment: I was interested in how the perk in question was worded. If you are standing still while power-attacking you get the 25% bonus? Or is it a more literal meaning - you have to be standing up and standing still to get the 25% bonus.

Comment: @Skizzlefrits: Power attacks are directional. To see what I mean, switch to third person view, and perform a power attack while standing still, walking backwards, walking forwards, or side to side. This is particularly easy to see with dagger animations.

Comment: so what you are saying is that Savage Strike does work while sneaking.Good to know, as it will add a lot of damage(33 base + shrouded gloves sneak attack x30 = 990 + powerattack 2.25x = 2227 + orc berzerk 2x = 4455). thats almost 500 extra damage. thank you for answering my question.

Comment: dual sneaking attacks waste less time than standing ones, so if you have to pick, choose the +50% to dual power attacks.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Is the definition of the power attack not "attacking while moving"?

Comment: @Bora, no it is not, hence the existence of 'standing power attacks' -  Power attacks are executed by holding down the attack button, not by pressing it while in motion. Holding down the attack button while moving in a variety of directions can give your power attacks additional effects, based on perks.

Comment: cool. Im going to be a dark elf and i'm just going to be going around and sneak attacking the guards. Pickpocketing people while their asleep and be breaking into people houses. And having the thief stone at my side is helpful. DarkElf Thief FTW!

Comment: @dylan you should definately be an Orsimer(Orc). They have the highest damage output and are the best theives. Their berzerker power is without a doubt the strongest racial ability in the game.

Comment: Also, if you use Dual wielding with a sword in right hand & dagger in left with a sneaking power attack you get the Multiplier with both weapons. This does not work with two daggers though. I am glad to hear Savage Strike will work with this too since soon I will be doing 12x & x30 Sneak attacks once I get Savage Strike & Dual Savagery to maximize my Sneak attacks with the Shrouded Gloves. 75% more Sneak damage will be sick & I need it Since I only Play on Master Level Difficulty.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I have the back stab perk and I snuck a dragon with the marked for death shout I took 95% of his health.

Comment: This one is actually a good answer. You can get 30x damage if you do sneak power attack with dagger