# Sneak-Attacking in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do power attack perks in Skyrim apply to sneak power attacks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38985/do-power-attack-perks-in-skyrim-apply-to-sneak-power-attacks)

If I'm sneaking and I attack an enemy while hidden I do a sneak-attack which does more damage, right?
But what if I, as a dual wielder from a crouching hidden state, dual power attack or dual "normal" attack? Does my character leave sneak-mode for the attack, and not getting the sneak multiplier, or does he stay in sneak-mode throughout the attack?
I'm asking cause the animation would suggest that he'd leave to attack then go back, but i wanted to be sure.
Thanks for any replies! :D